# Getting the full path of a DirectoryEntry

Tags: google-chrome-extension, filepath, google-chrome-app

Does anyone know how to get the full path of a `DirectoryEntry` object in a Chrome Packaged App, without any tildes or other shortcuts?

I am writing a [Google Chrome Packaged App](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html).  My app has a button where a user can choose a directory using [chrome.fileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) API.  When the directory choice comes back to my app, it is represented by a `DirectoryEntry` object, which is defined in the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#bib-FILE-API-ED).  The object looks like this in the console:

```
DirectoryEntry {
  filesystem: DOMFileSystem
  fullPath: "/to_read"
  isDirectory: true
  isFile: false
  name: "to_read"
  __proto__: DirectoryEntry
}
```

I am using Windows and the full path of the directory is

```
C:\Users\David\Desktop\to_read
```

I would like a function that can return that path or something close.  Unfortunately, the closest thing I found is [`chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html#method-getDisplayPath), but that returns the following:

```
~\Desktop\to_read
```

The return value from `getDisplayPath` is not useful to me, because I want to get the full name of the directory (including the drive) so I can compare it to some other full directory paths I have.

I tried calling `toURL()` on the `DirectoryEntry` and it returned an empty string.

**A bit about my project:** I want to write an iTunes library synchronizer as a Chrome Packaged App.  The iTunes library XML file contains full paths like `file://localhost/D:/David/Music/Bob/Bob%20Album/01%20Bob.mp3`.  The user will give my app access to his music folders, and I want to be able to tell if he gave me access to the right folders.

Comment: Have you considered using an `<input type="file"...` instead ?

Comment: As pointed out in an answer below, the mediaGalleries API may be what you really want. Otherwise consider filing a [feature request](http://crbug.com/). I think a `chrome.fileSystem.getFullPath` method would be reasonable to have in the platform. @ExpertSystem, a file input will not work here since it intentionally obscures the full path.

Comment: @KenRockot: What do you mean by "obscure" it ? Can't you get the path using `<fileInputElem>.value` ?

Comment: No, because `value` will have a path like `C:\fakepath\foo.xml`

Comment: OMG - You are right - I am blind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently (2014-01-10) not a feature of Chrome, but I have suggested it and they are working on it:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322952

Answer (score 2):

The only full paths available are those returned by getDisplayPath.

The mediaGalleries API may be a better fit for your project: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries.html#iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full path `path/to/the/file.mp3` and you want to load the file directly with tis you can do it but the solution is not perfect. Use the [`chrome.mediaGalleries` API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries.html) to ask where the user saves his music (in your case), then you can write a loop who check if one of the path repository is equal to a gallery.

For example if you got a file `path/to/the/file.mp3` from the xml file and your galleries list looks like `["D", "to", "Videos"]`, write a function to check if each component of the file's path is a gallery. In this case your code will find "to", so you can launch a second function who use `"the/file.mp3"`.

The second function has to use the given path and find if the gallery contains the right folders and finally the right file (use this [example by Google](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/media-gallery)). In the case you're trying to find `"the/file.mp3"` with the gallery `to` your loop has to find a directory named `"the"` then `"file.mp3"` (write a recursive function), if you find the file open it, otherwise come back to the first function if you haven't check all the galleries or all the path's component.

Comment: +1 for the sustained effort, but I think there is not a good way to "check if each component of the file's path is a gallery"?  Just because there is a gallery named "to" and a folder named "to" doesn't mean they are the same folder.  I asked on chromium-apps Google Group and someone said I should make a feature request on crbug.com, so I'll do that soon.