# Display full path instead of ~ prefixed path in linux chrome apps

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to display the full path of a selected file in a [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) on linux. When I invoke the filesystem [getDisplayPath](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-getDisplayPath) api I get the path of the selected file prefixed with ~. For example instead of /home/user/file.txt I get ~/file.txt. Is there a way to force the first format. A code snippet would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quoting the docs, "... may be made more readable for display purposes". I don't think you can control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to get the full path.

This is an open enhancement in Chrome (but not much happening there): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322952

Source: [Getting the full path of a DirectoryEntry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883803/getting-the-full-path-of-a-directoryentry)

Comment: Yep that enhancement is basically blocked on the chrome privacy team not liking it.