# getting full absolute path of a directory or file on a user's local system in chrome extension or app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get the full path of a chrome [fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) fileEntry.

I'm trying to use `getDisplayPath` to get the "full path of the file or directory on the local file system," but all that get's returned is `~/Documents/current_directory`

What I was hoping it would be is: `/home/user/Documents/current_directory`, or in other words, it's missing the home directory, and using `~` instead.

I want to get the absolute path of a file so that I can view it via url in the chrome browser.

I can use the chrome tabs api to do this:

```
var url = "file:///home/user/Documents/folder/file";
chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, function(tab) {
});
```

I need to give it an exact url.

According to this:
[Display full path instead of ~ prefixed path in linux chrome apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361959/display-full-path-instead-of-prefixed-path-in-linux-chrome-apps), a solution to my question may not exist.

I will accept any answer that helps me get the absolute path of a file or folder that exists in an arbitrary directory that a user selected using chrome's `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` function. Since a true solution may not exist, I will also accept clever/workaround answers (for example, the very least I can do is use a text input to ask a user for a string representing their home directory).

Comment: Are you really only interested in files that exist in the extension's directory?  The follow-up question would be:  What do you intend to do with the file after you know the path?

Comment: I am not interested in files that exist in the extensions directory. I am interested in files that exist in an arbitrary directory that a user selected using chrome's `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` function. I intend to open the file in chrome using the absolute path as shown above.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood.  Your sentence "I will accept any answer that helps me get the absolute path of a file or folder in a chrome extension. " is confusing.  It sounds like you want to retrieve a file or folder that is "in a chrome extension".  You might want to re-phrase that part.

Comment: good point, edited question

Comment: AFAIK there is way to get the absolute path. There was an internal proposal to add a function which would get it for you, but the chrome privacy team didn't want to give this information away so it did not go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the absolute path of a directory by making the user download a file to the directory using the downloads api. The download api then has the absolute path of the downloaded file.

With the absolute path of the directory and file names you have their full absolute paths

Comment: Fascinating. I can trigger a download of a robots.txt secretly and then delete it when done. Unfortunately though if the user has the setting "always ask for download location" it won't be secret. And there's no way to detect or silently fail if they have that setting.

Comment: @kzahel On-install permission warning _"Manage your downloads"_ is not exactly silent.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a file, you may want to grab the content of the file as a blob and use something like:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, function() {});
```

Comment: Seems not to be relevant to the question. I don't think the OP was asking how to get at the file's contents. If he was, his question is very poorly stated.

Comment: My ultimate goal is for a way to open up a file in chrome programattically. I believe that chrome.tabs.create({url: url}, function(tab) {}) is the best way to do that. To use this method I need to give it a file's full path, including the home directory. Chrome's display path chops off first part of the files url, as shown in my question above. I'm looking for any method that helps me get that full file url that I can use to open the file in chrome.

Comment: This solution is unlikely to work. According to [W3](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#url) the url given by the createObjectURL function looks like this: `blob:550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000#aboutABBA`